# Extending Mongo.Collection breaks find() method

Tags: meteor

Following the excellent [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#schema-design) I have tried to play with extending a collection. My ultimate aim is to create objects that manage insertion and update immediately as their values are updated. I've tried this with my `Order` class:

```
Order = class Order {
  constructor(customerId, orderDate){
    this.document = {};
    this.document.customerId = customerId;
    this.document.orderDate = orderDate;
    this.document._id = Orders.insert(this.document);
  }

  // some class methods go here.
}
```

My `orders` are uniquely defined by the customer id and date. So you cannot make two orders on the same day. Therefore I've extended the `Mongo.Collection` class with my own `OrderCollection` class. This sort of abstracts the data layer to ensure the data therein remains remains unique to it's key:

```
class OrderCollection extends Mongo.Collection{

  constructor(collectionName){
    super(collectionName);
    this.attachSchema(
      new SimpleSchema({
        customerId: { type: String }, 
        orderDate: { type: Date }
      })
    );  
  }

  insert(list, callback){
    // check if the actual order already exists
    if (list._id){
      return _id;
    }

    // we won't insert a new order if a matching one exists. 
    var order = Orders.findOne({
      customerId: list.customerId,
      orderDate: list.orderDate
    });
    if (order){return order._id;}

    // create order and return it. 
    return super.insert(list, callback);
  }

  remove(selector, callback){
    return super.remove(selector, callback);
  }
}

Orders = new OrderCollection("orders");
```

This all seems to work. When I create a new order it's either creating a new one, or it returns the existing one with the correct _id. So for example when I run `meteor reset` and then enter a new Order I retrieve the same `_id` as I do when I stop meteor, restart it and try the same insert again:

```
{ document:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  { customerId: 'QB6rEEJirGXS3oj6R',                                                                                                                                                                          
    orderDate: Fri Jan 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),                                                                                                                                                       
    _id: 'AwmygYsPnxR86Ks6D' } }
```

This is all well and behaving as expected. But I just cannot seem to retrieve any objects through subscriptions or calls to `Orders.find({}).fetch()` either on the client.

Even msavin:mongol tells me that the Orders collection is empty and even if I add new items to it through the monogl interface, they don't appear. What am I doing wrong?

*Update*

I'm using SimpleSchema and Collections2 and wonder if they somehow may not support the way I use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a beginner's issue. The above all worked, the issue was with the subscription on the client, instead of `instance.autorun(function...)` I had written `instance.autorun = function...`